# modular exponentiation where exponent is 1 (mod m)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Suppose I know that $ax + by \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$,
why would then, for any $0<s<m$ it would hold that $s^{ax} s^{by} \equiv s^{ax+by} \equiv s \pmod{m}$?

I do not understand the last step here. Is it some obvious exponentiation rule I'm overlooking here?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot upvote your answers, they're really useful. I haven't given the full information I see.   
 I should also have said that $m$ is a product of two (big) primes, and that $x$ and $y$ are two small primes.   
 Since $s$ is a random value $0<s<m$, I think I cannot say that $s$ is relatively prime to $m$ (as $s$ might be equal to one of the two divisors of $m$).

Comment: It should also have been $ax + by = 1$, this follows from that $x$ and $y$ are distinct primes. I will correct that above, if possible. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, due to my own above mistakes it become apparent now. Thanks :) I'll try to delete this question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false. $2*5 + 1*7 = 17 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, $0<2<4$ and $2^{17} \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

However, what is true is that for $s$ and $m$ coprime, $s^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totent function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

$s^{\phi(m)+1} \equiv s \pmod{m}$ holds even if $s$ and $m$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: Let $m=3$, $ax+by=4$. It is not the case that $2^4\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. So even primality of $m$ is not sufficient.

**Remark:** It is hard to guess what the intended result is. Perhaps this: If $s$ is relatively prime to $m$ and $ax+by\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(m)}$, then $s^{ax+by}\equiv s\pmod{m}$.